# value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.string can not be converted to jsonobject

Tags: java, android, json, doctype

I am a designer and have no idea about coding, I am reskining an app and after building apk I am having this error on signup screen when I enter all details and click on signup

> value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.string can not be converted to jsonobject

Here is the complete code on my `signupactivity.java` file.

```
    import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.amo.FillPocket.app.App;
import com.amo.FillPocket.common.ActivityBase;
import com.amo.FillPocket.util.CustomRequest;
import com.amo.FillPocket.util.Helper;

public class SignupActivity extends ActivityBase {


    EditText signupUsername, signupFullname, signupPassword, signupEmail;
    Button signupJoinBtn;

    private String username, fullname, password, email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        signupUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signupUsername);
        signupFullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signupFullname);
        signupPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signupPassword);
        signupEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signupEmail);

        signupJoinBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupJoinBtn);

        signupJoinBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                username = signupUsername.getText().toString();
                fullname = signupFullname.getText().toString();
                password = signupPassword.getText().toString();
                email = signupEmail.getText().toString();

                if (verifyRegForm()) {

                    if (App.getInstance().isConnected()) {

                        showpDialog();

                        CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, METHOD_ACCOUNT_SIGNUP, null,
                                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                                        Log.e("Profile", "Malformed JSON: \"" + response.toString() + "\"");

                                        if (App.getInstance().authorize(response)) {

                                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(i);

                                            ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(SignupActivity.this);

                                        } else {

                                            switch (App.getInstance().getErrorCode()) {

                                                case 300 : {

                                                    signupUsername.setError(getString(R.string.error_login_taken));
                                                    break;
                                                }

                                                case 301 : {

                                                    signupEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_email_taken));
                                                    break;
                                                }

                                                default: {

                                                    Log.e("Profile", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + response.toString() + "\"");
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                        hidepDialog();
                                    }
                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.e("Profile", "Malformed JSON: \"" + error.getMessage() + "\"");

                                hidepDialog();
                            }
                        }) {

                            @Override
                            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                params.put("username", username);
                                params.put("fullname", fullname);
                                params.put("password", password);
                                params.put("email", email);
                                params.put("clientId", CLIENT_ID);

                                return params;
                            }
                        };

                        App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.msg_network_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }


    public Boolean verifyRegForm() {

        signupUsername.setError(null);
        signupFullname.setError(null);
        signupPassword.setError(null);
        signupEmail.setError(null);

        Helper helper = new Helper();

        if (username.length() == 0) {

            signupUsername.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));

            return false;
        }

        if (username.length() < 5) {

            signupUsername.setError(getString(R.string.error_small_username));

            return false;
        }

        if (!helper.isValidLogin(username)) {

            signupUsername.setError(getString(R.string.error_wrong_format));

            return false;
        }

        if (fullname.length() == 0) {

            signupFullname.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));

            return false;
        }

        if (password.length() == 0) {

            signupPassword.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));

            return false;
        }

        if (password.length() < 6) {

            signupPassword.setError(getString(R.string.error_small_password));

            return false;
        }

        if (!helper.isValidPassword(password)) {

            signupPassword.setError(getString(R.string.error_wrong_format));

            return false;
        }

        if (email.length() == 0) {

            signupEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));

            return false;
        }

        if (!helper.isValidEmail(email)) {

            signupEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_wrong_format));

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){

        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home: {

                finish();
                return true;
            }

            default: {

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are receiving XML and trying to parse it as if were JSON.  That will not work.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.  A little more effort on your part is required, and we cannot debug the large block of code posted without you identifying where the problem occurs.

Comment: In short the response from server is wrong, server is probably sending you the HTML, it generally happens when server crash when a request is sent to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.string can not be converted to jsonobject
```

This does not seem to be fully your fault. Apparently API you are using is badly written and spits out pure HTML 404/500 error page in case when unhandled backend issue occur. This is unfortunately pretty common with half-baked or badly designed or untested software so if you do not have access to the source code to fix that but then there's no much you can do with this behavior. What is your fault however is lack of error handling in your code. You should **always** expect the worst which in this case means API timeout, lack of response, faulty response, incomplete response or malformed response and so on and be prepared. In case of your current code you need to `try/catch` response parsing code block and when exception occur handle it same way you would deal with other errors there.

Answer (score -1):

In short the response from server is wrong, server is probably sending you the HTML, it generally happens when server crash when a request is sent to it.